# About quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> I want to find the value $|\mathbb{Z}({\sqrt{2})/(3+\sqrt{2})}|,|\mathbb{Z}({\sqrt{13})/(5+\sqrt{13})}|$ and also the number of ideals of $\mathbb{Z}({\sqrt{13})/(5+\sqrt{13})}$.

But still not understand its concept. For example if $x=a+b\sqrt{2}$ I can substract $x$ by $b(3+\sqrt{2})=a-3b \in \mathbb{Z}$ so I can choose $a-3b\in\mathbb{Z}$ as representative for $x=a+b\sqrt{2}$ but $5=(3+\sqrt{2})(3-\sqrt{2})\in (3+\sqrt{2})$ so i can use just remainder of $a-3b$ when divide by 5 as representative of $\mathbb{Z}({\sqrt{2})/(3+\sqrt{2})}$ (i.e. $0,1,2,3,4$ and hence its order is $5$). Did I understand it correctly? How can I be sure that I cannot decrease the number of representative anymore?And how to write it formally when submit to the professor? What about the number of ideals?

Can anyone explain? Thanks for your help.

Comment: A booboob: $(3+\sqrt2)(3-\sqrt2)=7$ not $5$. Can you show that none of the integers $1,2,3,4,5,6$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $3+\sqrt2$? Wouldn't that show (together with the good start that you have) that the index is seven? But seven is a prime, so, in view of Lagrange's theorem from group theory, what can you say about the existence of intermediate groups? Let alone ideals.

Comment: The index is the norm of the ideal, which in the first case is $7$, see "Norm of ideals" and $Norm(I)=\# O_k/I$. This does not make the proof easier, but you know the result at least.